# How to make small movement of malfunctioning vehicle in confined space?

Tags: tools

I got a van with a malfunctioning transmission/transaxle. It behaves like in neutral no matter what I put it on, so I can't drive it. I want to move it to a house garage, but to enter that garage it needs to go uphill. The driveway is very confined, so I don't think a tow would be able to leave it in the position I want it. As things are, my best chance would be to have the tow leave it uphill in the driveway, let the car go downhill to get some momentum and turn to enter the garage, but the turn is too sharp, so I don't think it would work.

I was thinking that the surest scenario could be to use a winch to pull it into the garage, but I don't want to have to drill into the wall or ground to use as anchor. I was wondering if there was some sort of portable post that could be used for this. Something that would maybe convert the pulling force into a push into the ground without flipping over. Something like a low post on a tripod with 2 long legs extending forward with rubber for traction.

I haven't found something like this, and I'm not completely sure the physics of it make sense. In any case, if someone knows of a better solution, I'd be grateful to know about it.

Comment: Don't you have a group of friends that can push it by hand?

Comment: @HandyHowie uphill? Not enough. I also wouldn't want to try it. Since last time I pushed it with by hand (with help, on flat ground, a couple years ago), I've been feeling a pressure point in my spine. I don't want to further risk getting a herniated disk.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of towing it, use a solid tow bar and push it.

Comment: I have another vehicle, but it's much lighter. I don't think it has the strength to push the van uphill. Still, thanks, I didn't know about solid tow bars.

Comment: The "strength to push it up hill" is not so much of a problem as the strength of the *brakes*, to stop it rolling back down! If you do try rolling the van down hill *run the engine* even though you can't get the van into gear, so that you have *power assistance for the brakes.*

Answer (score 1):

Rent a car pusher.  It has electric motor and pushes your car for you.  Heavy duty can even push them up a driveway with a reasonable grade.  See link below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zGxrcQOUNo

Comment: That's super cool, but it doesn't seem like there's a place to rent one that's within my reach.